# Dynamic Number of Signers

Tags: docusignapi

I have a form that may get signed by a single user or multiple users.

I was going to have multiple copies of the form: first one with 1 signature box, second one with 2 signature boxes, 3rd one with 3 signature boxes and so on...

But we add/remove fields from the form very often, and I don't want to edit 4 or 5 different templates every time we add/remove a field.

Has anyone dealt with something like this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (unless you specify otherwise), all Recipient Roles within a Template are considered optional.  This means that you can do the following:

- Create a single template that contains the maximum number of
  recipients (and fields/tabs for all recipients).
- Each time you create an Envelope via API, include Recipient information in the "Create Envelope" API request only for the needed recipients (Roles).

Any Recipient Roles that you do not specify information for in the "Create Envelope" API request will simply not be included for the Envelope (and of course, if a Recipient isn't part of the envelope, their fields/tabs won't appear either).

One final note (albeit an obvious one) -- although all Recipient Roles within a Template are considered optional (unless you specify otherwise when creating the Template in the DocuSign UI), you must specify at least one recipient in order to send an Envelope.